# which Google Play services API contains com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager?

Tags: android, google-play

I am using google play services API, and from old version of code, i included the whole library. Now i want to use Selectively compiling APIs from this link https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup. But i can't find what does com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager  come from .

I already have this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
```

but none of them have.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The `AppStateManager` of the `Google Play Services` is **DEPRECATED**, so they have hidden the AppState play-services-dependency.

At the moment you can still get it via the following dependency, but it will probably get deleted soon.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:7.8.0'
```

or for Updated version use
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0'

Comment: Since it is deprecated, why they have kept it in the GamerHepler.java class used to implement to play services (https://goo.gl/Y2p4l2)? Any idea? Do they take time to update? And how are we supposed to proceed with new project, fix the class ourselves or use an old version?

Comment: One day after your comment, they updated the GameHelper class and simply get rid of it: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/commit/67a083fd355e31d2c7afd426e796a908a60a901d

Comment: Ya, @AladinQ saved games project has been deleted.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following dependency in build.gradle rember this is for old  **DEPRECATED**

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:9.0.0'
```

This is work for me